# Virtualbox Cant ping VMs in same LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ping

I have two hosts, with each of them running a single VM in VirtualBox, located in the same home LAN.
I have set bridged adapters for both VMs and the source IP address has the same subnet assigned as the destination IP address (source 192.168.18.15, destination 192.168.18.1).
When trying to pinging each other i get the response: Destination Host Unreachable.
In very rare random cases a connection is established but only for about 10 seconds before again getting the initial response.

[image: see here]

Pinging between hosts is possible. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you are not using Host Only mode. Should work fine - I have two hosts here each with VMs

Comment: Only bridged adapters are used

Comment: Strange - No issues here.  That setup is the same as Real Machines. Make sure Network Discovery is ON.

Comment: I have made the image inline. But please put text information as text, in your question.

Comment: I do not have many ideas (because what you want just works in the vast majority of cases).  Look at possible firewall limitations.  Default firewalls normally do not cause issues.

Comment: i have even disabled firewall for both machines and it still wont work